# Ref disappeared when loading image callback is invoked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

my code is like this below

```
const ImagePreview = forwardRef((props,ref) =>{
    const ref_canvas_pic = useRef();
    useImperativeHandle(ref,()=>({
        loadPic: (myfilepath) =>{
            console.log("1. ref_canvas_pic is ready?",ref_canvas_pic.current);
            chara.src = myfilepath;
            chara.onload = () => {
                console.log("2. ref_canvas_pic is ready?",ref_canvas_pic.current);
            }
        }
     }));

     return <canvas ref={ref_canvas_pic}  width="500" height="250" ></canvas>
});
```

Then, I call `loadPic` from the parent object.

```
useEffect(() =>{
    imagePreviewRef.current.loadPic(myfilepath);
},[myfilepath]);

return <ImagePreview ref={imagePreviewRef}></ImagePreview>
```

First `1.ref_canvas_pic is ready?` return the object, but second `2.ref_canvas_pic is ready?` returns null.

I guess something happens before the onload back is called.(maybe re-render??)

However where should I fix?